# Creating html table from XML using PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, algorithm

I'm trying to create an html table from xml using PHP.  The XML looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Device name="3" alias="THIS">
    <RecCommand name="CLICK">
        <GlobalState name="Light Is Off">
            <Conditions>
                <Device name="3">
                    <State name="LEVEL">
                        <Test name="LT">50</Test>
                    </State>
                </Device>
            </Conditions>
            <Commands>
                <Device name="3">
                    <Command name="ON">
                    </Command>
                </Device>
            </Commands>
        </GlobalState>
        <GlobalState name="Light Is On">
            <Conditions>
                <Device name="3">
                    <State name="LEVEL">
                        <Test name="GTE">50</Test>
                    </State>
                </Device>
            </Conditions>
            <Commands>
                <Device name="3">
                    <Command name="OFF">
                    </Command>
                </Device>
            </Commands>
        </GlobalState>
    </RecCommand>
</Device>
```

And the function I'm currently working on:

```
    function foo($parent) {
    if ($parent->children()->count() > 0) {
            $j = '<tr><td>' . $parent->getName();
            foreach($parent->attributes() as $attrName => $attrValue) {
                $j .= ' ' . $attrName. '=' . $attrValue;
            }
            echo $j;
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        //foreach ($parent->children() as $node) {
            //foo($node);
            foo($parent->children());
        //}
    }
    else {
            $j = $parent->getName();
            foreach($parent->attributes() as $attrName => $attrValue) {
                $j .= ' ' . $attrName. ' : ' . $attrValue;
            }
            $j .= ' ' . $parent;
            echo '<td>';
            echo $j;
            echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '<body>';
echo '<table border="1">';
foo($test);
echo '</table>';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
```

It hits all the elements and echos a simple table but I'd like to produce a table that mirrors the structure of the XML.  I've tried many different setups for the `<tr>` and `<td` tags but I can't get it right.  I always end up with far too many nested rows and columns and it looks like some crazy maze.

Comment: Is your xml normalized, so that the actual number of columns are static in your table? If so, is the idea that each outer element could have several rows on the table (where the outer element is repeated on each row for it's children elements)? Or is it as simple as each outer element = one row? If it's the latter, why not build the table outside of PHP and insert the rows dynamically?

Comment: Also, are you using simplexml or DOM as your xml abstraction?

Comment: Simplexml, but I'm not sure what you mean about building it outside of PHP.  Using XLST?

Comment: No, not XSLT, though that's one alternative that may work. I meant having an array of table rows and then using a foreach outside of the simplexml parsing bit that outputs each row in the array. That way you could output the array first using `print_r` to see if there is something wrong with your table syntax or something wrong with your loop itself.

Comment: It would also help if you could show the html table that you are hoping to end up with (formatted in question as HTML code, not as actual rendered html, please).

Comment: ok, give me a minute to post a table.

Comment: hint: use another simplexmlelement to create you HTML table.